# capturing repeated groups only in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I would like to capture all rows with patterns:

```
1234 2345 2345 6754

1234 2312

2345 4567 2345
```

which is groups of 4 digits only.

I tried the expression

```
((\d\d\d\d\s*)+?)
```

but it is capturing rows with non 4 digits group also. I.e.

```
1234 asdf 1232 2345 
or 

1234 231 2345
```

May I know what changes should I make to my current expression?

Thank You!

Comment: `^\d{4}(?:\s+\d{4})*$` or `(?m)^\d{4}(?:\s+\d{4})*$`. Note `\s*` can match an empty string, so you are not enforcing 4-digit numbers with your regex.

Comment: How are you matching that text? Are you using `findall`? Are you iterating over the lines? Depending on how you want to do you want to simply use `re.fullmatch` instead of `re.match` or specify the `^` and `$` anchors with `re.MULTILINE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match lines containing 4-digit sequences only (separated with whitespaces):

```
^\s*(\d{4}\b\s*)+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/30kEH6/1

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = "1234 5678 9101"
print(re.match(r'^\s*(\d{4}(\s+|\Z))+$', text))
```

1. `^` Matches start of the line.
2. `\s*' Matches 0 or more white space characters.
3. `(\d{4}(\s+|\Z))+` Matches 4 digits followed by either one or more spaces or the end of the string all repeated one or more times.
4. `$` Matches the end of the line.

[See Demo](http://ideone.com/3kDI7v)